# CXF Runtime Exception when casting Object to Map

Tags: string, apache, dictionary, casting, cxf

Using the latest Apache CXF 2.7.10 and getting runtime exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.util.Map     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.setSoapAction(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:111)

I checked that code and found this typecast. Message is a `Map<String, Object>`.

`(Map<?, ?>)message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS)`

In that code appears a poor assumption that an Object is always a Map.

I looking to work around this for now so I'll keep chasing the trace back.
In the mean time; anyone familiar with CXF know why my Object returned from Message.get() is a String and not a Map?

Answer (score 0):

The PROTOCOL_HEADERS value object should be a map which can used as HTTP headers.

You must did some change on the message context of PROTOCOL_HEADERS.